# Retry Connection Attempt is not working with JDBC Sink Connector Only

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Sample JDBC Sink Connector Config

```
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "connection.attempts":"1000",
    "connection.backoff.ms":"2000",
    "retry.backoff.ms":"3000",
    "max.retries":"100",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "pgr_G$$fbi!oo",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.2.221:5435/clt1278_envdev_dep_tran",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "topics": "DELETE_PG_HST_TRAN_DATA",
    "auto.create": "false",
    "table.name.format": "hst_tran_data",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id",
    "delete.enabled": "true"
}
```

### **Note**

These connection.attempts,'connection.backoff' properties can be changed and its working fine with source connector config but In sink connector not able to control these configs...

Is there anybody to help me to kick this issue?....[Error Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ApPC.png)

Answer (score 0):

The number of retries and interval between them in Sink Connector is managed by the following properties:

max.retries 
   The maximum number of times to retry on errors before failing the task.

```
 - Type: int
 - Default: 10
 - Valid Values: [0,...]
 - Importance: medium
```

retry.backoff.ms 
   The time in milliseconds to wait following an error before a retry attempt is made.

```
    - Type: int
    - Default: 3000
    - Valid Values: [0,...]
    - Importance: medium
```

I tested it and it worked for me. I think you must enter int value but you entered string value.

```
"connection.attempts":1000,
"connection.backoff.ms":2000,
"retry.backoff.ms":3000,
"max.retries":100
```